# integration of two curves when in 3rd or 4th quadrant

Tags: calculus, integration

I have been asked to find the area between two curves, both of which are in the 4th quadrant this should give a negative result unless I use $\int -f(x)$ is this correct? And if so, how do I tell when my result will be positive and when it will be negative without a graph?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easy fix for the negative area problem: use absolute value signs! To find the area between the two functions from $x=a$ to $x=b$, you can just do $$\int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)|dx$$ As for evaluating the integral, you can then divide the integral up into pieces where $f(x)-g(x)$ is negative and pieces where it is positive, then continue. Hopefully this clears things up.

Comment: that makes total sense!  the problem is I am asked to show that the area bound between $y=3x+3$ and $y=x^2+4x+1$ is given by $\int_{-2}^1 (-x^2-x+2)dx$.  Finding intersection the function I get is $f(x)=x^2+x-2$ It does make more sense to use absolute value than working out which quadrant it will be in.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: my problem being is how do I show that $∫_{−2}^1 (−x2−x+2)dx$ is correct?

Comment: You would have to show that it is always positive throughout the region you are integrating over.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the functions. If you do $\int_a^b f(x)-g(x)\ dx $ and $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x$ from $a$ to $b$, then you will always have a positive result. Generally you want to define it where the "smaller/more negative" function is $g(x)$ and subtract that from the "larger/more positive" function, $f(x)$.